# Google Spreadsheets multiple/scenario filter dropdown

Tags: filter, sum, google-sheets, validation

I can create drop down filter options for each of the dimensions in the spreadsheet:  month, description, and type.  using data validation and then sum(filter in Google Sheets.  I want to include an option in the drop-down to include all months, include all types, etc.  The end product would sum the amount based on the filters selected.  I can sum(filter based on individual selections but my question is how to sum the amounts if one of the scenarios was:  all months, groceries only, all descriptions.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgKUNhffHpmZdHZ3TGNXOUplN1R5UUlUSW5tVVp5b1E#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a Pivot Table. Then you have all this things in one view.
Select colums A to D. Go to Data/Pivot Table.
Add Month to Rows and Description to Colums (or vise versa) and add Amout to Values.
You'll see a total for all Descriptions/month and Grand total/month and /description.